# Several instances of Netbeans on Win 32 platform

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, windows-vista

Is it possible to have several instances of Netbeans running, as you can have with Visual Studio on Win 32 platform? I can just fire up one.

Comment: I have installed multiple versions of Netbeans (6.5, 6.7, 6.7.1) each one is separate from the others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use multiple instances of Netbeans, [specify a different `--userdir` directory](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqMultipleIdeInstances) for each instance. It's probably best to create a new shortcut or script for each instance.

Answer (score 6):

These are some examples that applies to all NetBeans version (3.6, 4.x, 5.x, 6.x, 7.x) on all platforms:

- **Windows**: netbeans.exe --userdir C:\MyOtherUserdir --cachedir "%HOME%\Locale Settings\Application Data\NetBeans\7.1\cache"
- **Unix**: ./netbeans --userdir ~/my-other-userdir
- **Mac OS**: /Applications/NetBeans.app/Contents/MacOS/executable --userdir ~/my-other-userdir

Comment: on linux I made a little script that copies my latest user dir and run the second instance with that (http://amanica.blogspot.com/2014/04/bye-eclipse-preventor-of-development.html)